# Android Studio открывает проект и подсвечивает несуществующие ошибки

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Я извиняюсь я не знаю как по другому назвать вопрос. Суть такая Android Studio открывает все классы проекта и подсвечивает что там есть ошибки хотя их нет, проект запускается и компилируется, я не пойму что такое. Вот ошибки:

```
Unresolved reference: activityViewModels
'public open fun toString(): java.lang.String defined in app.supermoms.club.ui.activity.home.allmodules.babyprogress.ModuleBabyProgress' clashes with 'public open fun toString(): kotlin.String defined in app.supermoms.club.uielements.CircleNumberListener': return types are incompatible
Cannot access 'java.lang.Object' which is a supertype of 'app.supermoms.club.ui.activity.home.allmodules.babyprogress.ModuleBabyProgress'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
Class 'ModuleBabyProgress' must override public final fun hashCode(): Int defined in androidx.fragment.app.Fragment because it inherits many implementations of it
Unresolved reference: activityViewModels
Type 'Lazy<TypeVariable(T)>' has no method 'getValue(ModuleBabyProgress, KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate
Cannot access 'java.lang.Object' which is a supertype of 'androidx.fragment.app.Fragment'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
Cannot access 'java.lang.Object' which is a supertype of 'app.supermoms.club.ui.activity.home.allmodules.babyprogress.ModuleBabyProgress'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Я предоставлю скриншот, но не из-за того что мне лень писать а из-за того что так более понятней, проблему я описал выше. Причем это не один проект, во всех проектов на kotlin такие проблемы, иногда анализ кода вообще не работает, java вроде все нормально, не пойму что такое.

Comment: В таких случаях стоит в первую очередь InvalidateCacheAndRestart выполнить из меню IDE. Коли не поможет - пробовать удалять служебные папки в проекте - типа .idea, build, .gradle. Если и это не помогает - найти где gradle хранит свой кэш на уровне ОС и его удалить. Иногда помогает перестановка IDE. Иногда - перезагрузка компа (особенно в случае яблочного железа). Иногда - проблема в пустом комментарии в разметке или лишней в ней строчки или отстутствии экранирования спец. символов в strings.xml.

Comment: Спасибо. InvalidateCacheAndRestart , перезагрузка, Rebuild проекта не помогла, переустановка тоже не помогла. Служебные папки проекта не пробовал еще удалять из-за того что во всех проектах kotlin такое, java что интересно вроде нормально.

Comment: Единственная мысль есть переустановить систему, но это уже крайний случай. Попробую сперва что вы мне предложили.

Comment: Не помогло. Если это сделать код перестает анализироваться, если потом InvalidateCacheAndRestart сделать опять то же самое. Те же ошибки

Comment: А если пустой проект на котлине создать? Будет тоже самое? И попробуйте поиграться с версиями gradle плагина андроида и котлина. Возможно тут какой-то конфликт. Ну и/или версию IDE поменять (поставив рядом более старую или новую)

Comment: Ну в новом проекте все нормально на котлин, только вот мне надо над старыми работать, попробую со структурой проекта как вы и советуете поиграться. Спасибо вам. Последние надежды перед переустановкой системы.

Comment: Нет не помогло. Еще заметил если к строке с ошибкой курсор подвести вылазит такая ошибка Cannot access 'java.lang.Object' which is a supertype of 'app.supermoms.club.ui.activity.home.fragments.feed.FeedNoAuthFragment'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies Ну я это в ошибках ее вроде писал.

Comment: Может у вас что-то в конфиге проектов сломалось при, например, апдейте IDE и переходе с 8 версии жавы на 11-ую? Что если ваши старые проекты залить в к-л GitHub, удалить напрочь с компа и склонировать из меню IDE?

Comment: Я не знаю. Как думаете если систему переустановить заработает?

Comment: Стоит проверить) Переустановка системы может не помочь, если проблема - в файлах проекта.

Comment: Самое что интерестное что все запускается и компилируется вот только все красное от ошибок. Не могу же я так код писать.

Comment: Такое бывает да) Сам пару месяцев назад пару дней пытался понять в чём причина. У меня это в тот раз было из-за комментария пустого в разметке. В другой раз - опечатка в пакете для flavor. Пару раз кэш градла ломался. Пару раз - что-то не то было в .idea/libraries - их удаление помогло. Других случаев пока что не встречал. Сама ситуация не то чтобы уникальная - IDE - софт, а он всегда с багами)

Comment: Ну буду переустанавливать систему надеюсь поможет. В любом случае спасибо вам, я напишу если помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да переустановка системы помогла. Но если кто то знает что это было пишите. Подозреваю что дело было в глюке самой ide когда ее переустанавливал я все поудалял, но видимо не все, потому что когда она была переустановлена, то все равно находила автоматом открывала прошлый проект.