# Как найти ошибки в коде, если их нет?

Tags: android, обработка-ошибок

Началось всё с того, что посыпался жесткий диск и начались проблемы с считыванием файлов. Диск поставил новый, скопировал проект на него, битые файлы восстановил из архивов. Теперь всё читается, ни в одном из файлов (проверил все до единого!) при открытии ошибок не показывает, всё чистенько. Проект компилируется, в плеймаркет выложил его без проблем, никаких нареканий не было. Но несколько напрягают вот эти подчёркивания.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В других проектах такого не наблюдается, значит дело не в Android Studio. Пробовал Build/Clean Project - Rebuild Project, Invalidate Caches/Restart, Analise/Inspect Code. Нигде ошибок нет.
Как найти, в чём беда?

Comment: Подчёркиваются только папки, не конкретные файлы? Попробуйте переключить вид на Project, Project Files - возможно покажет проблемный файл. Скорее всего проблема в файлах конфигурации. Если оба вида не покажут ничего конкретного - то наверное надо чистить проект вручную и по новой импортировать в студию, но не факт что поможет.

Comment: @woesss, кроме тех трёх подчеркиваний, что на скрине, больше нигде ничего не подчёркивает при любом виде.

Comment: Мое мнение это лаги Android Studio, я с таким постоянно сталкиваюсь. Мой совет, если не такой кошмар как у меня был: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1360118/android-studio-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8 перезайдите в Android Studio, если не помогло то просто не обращайте внимание.